# how to solve VM Exception while processing transaction: out of gas

Tags: solidity, contract-development, web3js, out-of-gas, ganache

i am trying to call this function with help of web3.js in ganache testrpc but it is giving me error of  VM Exception while processing transaction: out of gas

i have tried to increas gas of ganache to 999999999999 still its not work...

> function initialEscrowDetail(uint transactionId,address partyB,uint
>   amount,bool condition){
>
> ```
>     escrowDetail[transactionId].originator=msg.sender;
>     escrowDetail[transactionId].beneficiary=partyB;
>     escrowDetail[transactionId].amount=amount;
>     escrowDetail[transactionId].payoutCondition=condition;
>     escrowDetail[transactionId].escrowCompleted=false;
> }
> ```

[image]

Comment: please share the code

Comment: thanks but issue is resolved. ganache testRPC is waste of time in reallife dapps testing. now i have started private test blockchain.

Comment: testrpc is also private EVM :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default gas in web3 if it is not specified is 90k. Since each new storage modifications cost 20k with 5 storage modifications you were using more than 100k of gas.

You can add an optional last parameter with the transaction gas

```
escrow.initialEscrowDetail(1,"0x0",200,true, { gas: 1000000 });
```